# dev:watch does not reload bundles on JBoss Fuse 6.3.0

Tags: maven, jbossfuse, karaf

I am porting my code from JBoss Fuse 6.2.1 to JBoss Fuse 6.3.0.

On my development environment I used Maven to build -SNAPSHOTS of my Java projects, and have them automatically deployed using `dev:watch` command.

I installed my bundle with `install mvn:my.groupid/my-artifactid/version-SNAPSHOT` and then `dev:watch ID`.
Following `mvn install` builds do not get automatically loaded inside JBoss Fuse, no messages in any log.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default configuration has changed between versions.
Property `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.localRepository` was not defined in 6.2.1 (thus defaulting to `~/.m2/repository`), now defaults to `${karaf.data}/repository` on 6.3.0

So to reenable previous behaviour, set the property to

```
#Linux
org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.localRepository=~/.m2/repository  
#Windows
org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.localRepository=/Users/alessandro/.m2/repository
```

Property is defined in `etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg`

**version 6.2.1**

```
# Path to the local maven repository which is used to avoid downloading
# artifacts when they already exist locally.
# The value of this property will be extracted from the settings.xml file
# above, or defaulted to:
#     System.getProperty( "user.home" ) + "/.m2/repository"
#
#org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.localRepository=
```

**version 6.3.0**

```
# Path to the local Maven repository which is used to avoid downloading
# artifacts when they already exist locally.
# The value of this property will be extracted from the settings.xml file
# above, or defaulted to:
#     System.getProperty( "user.home" ) + "/.m2/repository"
# leaving this option commented makes the system dependent on external configuration, which is not always desired
# "localRepository" is the target location for artifacts downloaded from "remote repositories", it's not
# searched for already available artifacts, unless added explicitly to "defaultRepositories"
# by default internal local repository is used to have behavior independent of the content of ~/.m2/repository
org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.localRepository = ${karaf.data}/repository
```