# Deployment in Jboss fuse using Maven

Tags: maven, jbossfuse

I have created a Fuse integration project in developer studio 9.0.2 and I'm using jboss-fuse-karaf-6.3.0 as the runtime container.

I want to deploy this project using Maven, but not able to figure out -

1. How and where to give server URL, user name and password for the deployment ?
2. Does project gets deployed to fabric or karaf ?

Will appreciate if anybody can help with some pointers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you wish to deploy *from* Maven? Is this task for production or development?

Comment: Thanks Alessandro.I want to deploy my project, that I created in developer studio to local karaf server using maven. I'm just starting with a POC. Eventually, this approach will be used for development environment.  I'm not able to figure out how this deployment will happen through maven. Is there a plugin that maven provides for deployment  to karaf container ?

Answer (score 1):

Is that server running locally or remote?

1. Locally you can simply define the server in the servers view and then use Add context menu to deploy your project.
2. it gets deployed to Karaf

Answer (score 1):

When building projects with Maven I use `osgi:install` and `dev:watch` commands (available in both JBoss Fuse and vanilla Karaf). The following setup works well for a development machine.

First build with Maven using **install** goal, so the artifact gets installed in local repository.
Then issue `osgi:install` (see [Manual Deployment](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Deploying_into_the_Container/files/DeployBundle-Manual.html) in JBoss Fuse docs) command in your container to install your bundle. Job done!

```
> osgi:install mvn:it.your.package/your-artifact/1.0.0
```

Once the bundle is installed you will see a message like

> Bundle ID: 352

This is the ID of the bundle installed. Issue the following command:

```
> dev:watch 352
```

> Watched URLs/IDs:
>   352

Now every time you rebuild with Maven, the bundle gets redeployed automatically.

Watch out some settings to be changed if [dev:watch does not reload bundles on JBoss Fuse 6.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40743113/423955)

**edit**: use `-SNAPSHOT` in your version with this setup. Regular versionsmay not redeploy correctly because the container *sees* the version is the same and may use previously loaded classes, thus causing classloading issues.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro for such a detailed answer.This is useful.May be I haven't comprehensively explained my problem, my apologies for that. What I'm looking for is doing deployment by ONLY running the pom file( just like I ran mvn install ,and project is installed in local reop). I can't issue any command from karaf terminal  (> osgi:install mvn:it.your.package/your-artifact/1.0.0) . This pom will be a part of automated process, which will build and deploy the project. All that user will do is - run the pom. Can you provide some guidance on how  deployment section in POM will look like  ?

Comment: What about some simple deploy task that copies all artifacts in JBoss Fuse `deploy/` dir? Bundles will be installed and started automatically.